# Получить GET-параметры с декодированием из url

Tags: javascript, html, url, get, формы

В url передаются get-параметры. Примерный вид url:
**https://site.com/testing?ticket=%5B000038%5D&select=1&qualcomm=Eto+moi+komment**

Передаю эти параметры в поля формы с помощью скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getQueryParam(param) {
    var result =  window.location.search.match(
        new RegExp("(\\?|&)" + param + "(\\[\\])?=([^&]*)")
    );

    return result ? decodeURI(result[3]) : "";
}

window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id").value =  getQueryParam("ticket");
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm").value =  getQueryParam("qualcomm");        
};</script>
```

Вопрос:

1. как декодировать знак **+** назад в **пробел**, потому что в поле заполняется строка вида **Eto+moi+komment**
2. в **url get-параметр select** имеет значение **1** или **2** - это значение **radio-кнопки**. Как мне проверить значение в url и в соответствии с этим сделать активным одну из radio-кнопок в форме, т.е. если **select=1**, то radio-кнопка с **id=rb1** сделать **checked** и соответственно если **select=2**, то сделать **ckecked id=rb2**

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, вот так:

```js
var loc='https://site.com/testing?ticket=%5B000038%5D&select=2&qualcomm=Eto+moi+komment';
//var loc=window.location.href;

function getQueryParam(param) {
    var params =  new URLSearchParams(loc.split('?')[1]);
    return params.get(param);
}

window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id").value =  getQueryParam("ticket");
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm").value =  getQueryParam("qualcomm");
        document.querySelector(`#rb${getQueryParam("select")}`).checked = true;
};
```

```html
<body>
<input type='text' id='pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id'>
<input type='text' id='pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm'>
    <p><input id="rb1" type="radio"> 1</p>
    <p><input id="rb2" type="radio"> 2</p>
    <p><input id="rb3" type="radio"> 3</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Плюсы пропали, но в консоли ошибка "Cannot set property 'checked' of null" и radiobutton не выбирается...

Comment: Посмотри еще раз, я подправил ответ. Может теперь получится.

Comment: Выбирается всегда второй radiobutton. Друг, у меня короче их всего два - value у них "Хорошо" и "Плохо". Так вот скажи пожалуйста, правильно ли я написал условие if и как теперь эту функцию вызвать: `function ifChecked() {
 if (getQueryParam("ticket") = 1) {
    document.getElementById('pwebcontact228_field-squality_0').checked = true;
 } else {
    document.getElementById('pwebcontact228_field-squality_1').checked = true;
 };
}`

Comment: Функция возвращает строку, а не число, поэтому надо сравнивать со строкой: if (getQueryParam("ticket") == '1')

Comment: И radiobutton я так понял у тебя зависит от параметра select, а не от ticket

Comment: посмотри пожалуйста код, я закинул в новом комментарии, какая ошибка в синтаксисе?

Comment: Да, я поправил уже, ticket заменил на select и все равно...

Comment: ты второй раз объявляешь функцию, вместо вызова, нужно просто ifChecked();

Comment: Да пожалуйста))

Answer (score 0):

```
function getQueryParam1(param) {
    var params =  new URLSearchParams(window.location.href.split('?')[1]);
    return params.get(param);
}

function ifChecked() {
    if (getQueryParam("select") == 1) {
       document.getElementById('pwebcontact228_field-squality_0').checked = true;
    } else {
       document.getElementById('pwebcontact228_field-squality_1').checked = true;
    };
}

window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id").value =  getQueryParam1("ticket");
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm").value =  getQueryParam1("qualcomm");   
        ifChecked();    
};
```

Ошибка **unexpected token ;**
какой правильный синтаксис?